Architecting a gRPC service for fetching/submitting surveys
I've recently been getting into gRPC and *.proto files. I've been working on a .proto file that describes fetching and submitting surveys. A couple things I'm thinking of:
A Survey is made up of multiple Questions
message Survey {
    int32 id = 1; // Unique ID for the survey
    string title = 2; // Title of the survey
    repeated Question questions = 3; // List of questions
}

A Question can be one of many question types (which are excluded from the post for brevity)
message Question {
    int32 id = 1; // Unique ID for the question
    string text = 2; // The question text
    bool optional = 3; // Whether this question can be skipped or not

    // There are many types of questions
    oneof question_type {
        MultipleChoiceQuestion multiple_choice = 4;
        FreeformQuestion freeform = 5;
        IntQuestion pos_int = 6;
        TimestampQuestion timestamp = 7;
    }
}

An Answer to a Question should be one of an answer type that matches that Question specs
message Answer {
    int32 question_id = 1; // The id of the Question this answer corresponds to

    oneof answer_type {
        AnswerSkipped skipped = 1; // If the question was skipped
        int32 selected_option = 2; // 0-indexed selection for MultipleChoiceQuestion
        string freeform_response = 3; // For FreeformQuestion
        int32 int_response = 4; // For IntQuestion
        google.protobuf.TimeStamp timestamp_response = 5; // For TimeStampQuestion
    }
}

A SurveyService should allow for fetching and submitting surveys. Keeping track of each individual survey instance that gets sent to a client might also be useful.
service SurveyService {
    rpc GetSurvey(GetSurveyRequest) returns (GetSurveyResponse) {}

    rpc SubmitSurvey(SubmitSurveyRequest) returns (SubmitSurveyResponse) {}
}

message GetSurveyRequest {
    int32 survey_id = 1; // ID of the survey to retrieve
}

message GetSurveyResponse {
    int32 survey_instance_id = 1; // The ID for this particular survey session
    Survey survey = 2; // The requested survey
}

message SubmitSurveyRequest {
    int32 survey_instance_id = 1; // The client should get this from GetSurveyResponse
    repeated Answer answers = 2; // The answers should line up with the question order
}

message SubmitSurveyResponse {
    bool success = 1; // TODO: explain different error cases through enums?
}

I have a couple of questions:

What was your experience implementing oneof with JSON/REST? I believe OpenAPI offers something similar to this, but what if you don't use OpenAPI?
This design fetches and submits whole surveys. Has anyone tried something different to keep track of partially filled-out surveys?
I define a skipped answer_type, which is just an enum with a single choice, SKIPPED. Is there a better way to do this?
It's technically possible to send invalid values like an invalid survey_instance_id, or an invalid list of answers that don't line up with the survey questions. How do you handle this type of validation?

